# Can I put "the" in front of "news" here?

Tags: definite-article

> U.S. President Barack Obama looked weary when he responded Thursday to
>   **news** of yet another mass shooting when he said: "Somehow, this has
>   become routine."
>
> [Oregon college shooting won't likely lead to tighter gun control,
>   experts say](http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/america-gun-control-1.3254065)

Can I put "**the**" in front of " **news**" here? If I can, what is the difference?

Comment: This is another case of "headlinese" (see https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=headlinese)

Comment: Yes, you can. I don't really have a good explanation of why though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "news" and "the news" are both perfectly natural and idiomatic here.  The meaning is the same, but there is a very slight difference in emphasis or tone.

"responded to the news of..." emphasizes "news" more, and suggests that "the news" is a single, important thing with which the reader is probably already familiar.  For the sentence in question, I think this is actually slightly more appropriate, because of the dramatic, front-page nature of the event.

On the other hand, for more mundane subjects, the article-free version fits slightly better: "Obama did not even bother to respond to news of a small increase in the employment rate announced earlier this week."